# Я так понимаю, что на офсайте убрали 32-битный дистрибутив?

Tags: java

[image: список загрузок]

Я так понимаю, что на офсайте убрали 32-битный дистрибутив?

Comment: есть только на 8 версию.

Answer (score 2):

Да, начиная с Java 9, Oracle перестал поставлять 32-битные сборки JDK.

Толкового официального заявления по этому поводу я не нашел, нашел только [твит](https://twitter.com/mreinhold/status/912311207935090689) от главного архитектора Java Platform Group Марка Рейнхольда:

> Sorry, but we have no plans to ship 32-bit builds of JDK 9. We’re trying to focus more on the future than the past.
>
> *Простите, но у нас нет планов поставлять 32-битные сборки JDK 9. Мы пытаемся сосредоточиться на будущем, а не на прошлом.*

Это подразумевает, что 32-битных сборок не будет и для последующих версий JDK.

Переходите на x64. Если требуется x86, можете рассмотреть альтернативные сборки OpenJDK ([ojdkbuild](https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild), [zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/)), либо собрать JDK сами, либо остаться на JDK 8.

Аналогичные вопросы на английском:

- [Can Java 9 run on a 32-bit OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46356345/can-java-9-run-on-a-32-bit-os)
- [Java 10 (and following) on 32-Bit systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976684/java-10-and-following-on-32-bit-systems)